# Field 'tag_number' expected a number but got 'КР-02211'

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have this problem my urls.py is:

```
path('cabinet/<str:pk>/update/',
         views.BookUpdateView.as_view(),
         name='book-update'),
```

models.py

```
tag_number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Tag number', validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1),
        MaxValueValidator(MAX_TAG_NUMBER),
    ])
```

views.py

```
class BookUpdateView(core.UpdateView):
    form_class = TagForm
    template_name = 'book_update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.tag_number = self.object.generate_tag()
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Why I have this mistake?

```
Field 'tag_number' expected a number but got 'КР-02211'.
```

Comment: Your `generate_tag()` generates thags that are incopatible with the type of your field (`PositiveIntegerField`), since it includes `KP-`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.generate_tag()` does not return an object of a type that is acceptable by your `tag_name` field. Indeed, your `tag_name` field is a `PositiveIntegerField`, so that means it can only store *integral numbers*, not text. Your `generate_tag()` however returns `KP-02211`, while it does end with a sequence of digits, it starts with `KP-`, and this can not be stored.

You can change the field to a `CharField`, for example with:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # …
    tag_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

or you can alter the `generate_tag` method to only return a number between 1 and `MAX_TAG_NUMBER`.